# Why not enough input arguments in nlcon in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in MATLAB with the function fmincon, but there appears a problem with the nonlinear constraints, as MATLAB tells that there are not enough input arguments.
This is my nlcon funtion:

```
function [c,ceq] = nlcon(w_md2,std)
c =[];
ceq = w_md2'*std-1;
end
```

that's the execution of fmincon:

```
covMat  = cov(mon_ret) ;  
[corMat, std] = corrcov(covMat);
w0 = repmat(n1, port_size, 1);
md2function = @(w_md2) md2(covMat, w_md2);
nonlincon = @nlcon;
w_md_2 = fmincon(md2function, w0, [], [], Aeq, Beq, lbnds, ubnds, nonlincon)
```

and that`s the error:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in nlcon (line 3)
ceq = w_md2'*std-1;

Error in fmincon (line 639)
        [ctmp,ceqtmp] = feval(confcn{3},X,varargin{:});

Error in main (line 60)
   w_md_2 = fmincon(md2function, w0, ...

Caused by:
    Failure in initial nonlinear constraint function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.
```

Would be really glad if someone could help as I am at total newby to MATLAB.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-nonlcon) says that the function passed as argument `nonlincon` should take one input argument. That means that it is called with only one input argument, and `std` remains undefined.

You probably want to do

```
nonlincon = @(x)nlcon(x,std);
```

That way you create an anonymous function that takes one input argument, and calls your function with the value of `std` you computed earlier.